# Hide field on lightning-record-edit-form if the user has read only access to it

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning

In LWC, I've requirement to hide the field on lightning-record-edit-form if the user has Read-only access to that field. For example, if the user has Read-Only access to 'Phone' field on Contact object, then when this lightning-record-form is displayed to that user, the Phone field should be displayed on the form.
Please check below sample html code for LWC:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName} onsuccess={successHandler}>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName" required> </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName" required> </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone" required> </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Email" required> </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" value={accountId} disabled>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <div class="slds-var-m-top_medium slds-float_right">
                    <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="Cancel" class="slds-m-right_small" onclick={hideModal}>
                    </lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" label="Save">
                    </lightning-button>
                </div>
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Is there any standard method or option available to do this or we need to write custom logic to implement this? Can you please share what custom logic to write, if that's the only way?

Answer (score 0):

We can construct a list of fields in the Apex with using below code

```
List<Strig> fields = new List<String>();
Set<String> fieldNameSet = new Set<String>{'FirstName', 'LastName', 
'Email', 'Phone', 'AccountId'};
for(SObjectField field :sObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values()){
    if(fieldNameSet.contains(field.getName())
        && field.getDescribe().isAccessible()
        && field.getDescribe().isUpdateable()
        && field.getDescribe().isCreateable()){
        fields.add(field.getName());
    }
}
return fields;
```

iterate this returned **fields** inside the lightning-record-edit-form